# Change like to likes in technical skills cv

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

The CV has an area of technical skills in which you can add multiple tags of things you use or like.  Please change the output from like to likes:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a larger screenshot? Sorry, can't tell where that is.

Comment: Do a preview of your cv.

Comment: Also if you have a cv so that you can preview it as a pdf: http://stackoverflow.com/jobs/apply/preview-pdf

Comment: Ah. I didn't realize it was on the pdf preview. I'll add it to the pile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These were originally intended as verbs, i.e. shorthand for "tags they *like*" and "tags they *dislike*". However, as you imply, it's not clear or consistent with the other headers, which are nouns. We'll get this fixed soon. Thanks for the report!

Comment: Looks good now, just exported.